# Sales receipt, multiple choices (if/else), while loop, customer ability to change selections

Tags: java, if-statement, while-loop, receipt

None of the other posts seemed to fit accordingly.
I'm really struggling with producing this program without errors. I've come up with this below, however, if you run the program it is not adequately looping and if you choose the same candy twice the math isn't adding to the previous selection.

For the second part, I need to recode to adjust so that the customer may change the current selections if they'd like. So, I need the first part running perfectly.

```
import java.util.Scanner; //Program uses Scanner
import java.util.Calendar; //Program uses calendar

public class ClairAndreaG005PA2
{//Begin class ClairAndreaG005PA2

 public static void main(String[] args)
  {
   /**Begin method. The customer is asked whether to proceed with a candy purchase.
   * As long as the candy choice is in the proper range, prompt for the quantity,
   * calculate the item total and subtotal; otherwise, print an error message. If it’s 
   * the first item in the purchase, ass it to the sales, a receipt with a $ sign for the
   * item total. If not format the item without a $ sign for the item total 
   * and add it to the sales receipt. Start the process again when the customer wants
   * to add another candy purchase. When the customer is done, the sales tax and the
   * total calculated, the sales receipt is finalized and printed.
   */

    int quantity = 0,
       formatFirstItem = 1,
       choice = 0;


    final double TAX_RATE = .0825; //tax rate declared

    double price = 0,
      itemTotal = 0,
      subtotal = 0,
      taxAmount = 0,
      total = 0;

    char proceed = ' '; //proceed variable for loop

    String candy = new String();

    Calendar dateTime = Calendar.getInstance(); //situational date and time

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

     String salesReceipt = String.format("%n%nFAIRYTALE SWEETS%n"
                                      + "North Star Mall%n"
                                      + "San Antonio, TX%n"
                                      + "Date: %n", dateTime
                                      + "Time: %n", dateTime);

    //Initiating variables and calculations

    System.out.printf("%nDo you want to proceed with your candy purhase? \'Y\' or \'N\': ");
    proceed = input.nextLine().charAt(0);
    //End Prompt 1

    while(Character.toUpperCase(proceed) == 'Y')
    {
      System.out.printf("%nFAIRYTALE SWEETS"
                    + "%n%n1. Arabian Nights Chocolate Coins - 1 lb. Bag %5s%,7.2f"
                    +"%n2. Beauty and the Beast Lollipops - 1 lb. Bag %,12.2f"
                    +"%n3. Mad Hatter Jelly Beans - 1 lb. Bag %,20.2f"
                    +"%n4. Pinocchio's Candy Cones - Each  %,23.2f"
                    +"%n5. Sleeping Beauty Caramel Apples - Each %,17.2f"
                    +"%n%nEnter your choice: ", "$", 2.25, 2.50, 1.75, 0.75, 1.25);
              choice = input.nextInt();
     //Prompt 2 Candy Menu

     if(choice > 0)
     {if(choice < 6)
        {if(choice == 1)
          {candy = "Arabian Nights Chocolate Coins";
              price = 2.25;
          }
          else
          {if(choice == 2)
            { candy = "Beauty and the Beast Lollipops";
                price = 2.50;
            }
            else
            {if(choice == 3)
              {candy = "Mad Hatter Jelly Beans";
                  price = 1.75;
              }
              else
              {if(choice == 4 )
                {candy = "Pinocchio's Candy Cones";
                    price = 0.75;
                }
                else
                {candy = "Sleeping Beauty Caramel Apples";
                    price = 0.75;
                 }
               }
             }
          }
          System.out.printf("%nQuantity for %s: ", candy);
    quantity = input.nextInt();

    //quantity of selections
     }
     else
      { System.out.println("Invalid candy choice! Try again.");
     }

     //Choices and selections

    itemTotal = quantity * price; //calculation 1
    subtotal += itemTotal; //calculation 2

    System.out.printf("%nWould you like to make another candy purchase? \'Y\' or \'N\': ");
         proceed = input.next().charAt(0);

         if(formatFirstItem == 1 )
         {
           salesReceipt += String.format("%n%s"
                                    + "%n      %d @ $%.2f ex. %-24s $%,10.2f%n", candy,
                                  quantity, price, " ", itemTotal);
           formatFirstItem = 0;
         }
         else
         {
           salesReceipt += String.format("%s"
                                    + "%n      %d @ $%.2f ea. %-25s %,10.2f%n", candy,
                                  quantity, price, " ", itemTotal);

         }
  //End if FormatFIrst Item is 1 or else formatFirstItem NOT 1
    }
    }//End while loop selection


    taxAmount = TAX_RATE * subtotal;// calculation 3
    total = taxAmount + subtotal; // calculation 4

    salesReceipt += String.format("%n%36s %-6s $%,10.2f"
                                + "%n%36s %-7s %,10.2f"
                                + "%n%n%36s %-6s $%,10.2f%n", "SUBTOTAL:   ", " ",
                              subtotal, "TAX @ 8.250%:  ", " ", taxAmount,
                              "TOTAL:  ", " ", total);
    System.out.printf("%s", salesReceipt); 
      }
}
```

Let me know!

Comment: First thing that would probably help you a lot is if you refactor this massive block of code into separate methods to help improve readability. In particular, you should look at  the [Single Responsibility](https://codeburst.io/understanding-solid-principles-single-responsibility-b7c7ec0bf80) principle. Secondly, you need to be more specific on what "adequately" means to you. Is it throwing errors? If so, which errors? Is the efficiency too low? What exactly is the issue with it?

Comment: Thank you I will read the principle. As for errors, it is compiling fine I just am having trouble getting the loop to restart when there is an invalid selection. And if they choose the same candy it adds the candy as another separate entity on the sales receipt rather than to the previous candy selection already choosen.

Comment: Ignore the previous article I linked, this one explains things better: https://towardsdatascience.com/solid-programming-part-1-single-responsibility-principle-efca5e7c2a87

Comment: As for your counting issue, I'm struggling to identify where you keep track of each individual candy selected. I'm mainly just seeing you add the price total together. You may want to look into making a `Order` class that holds the candies as a generalized `Candy` class that stores their own values of price, name, and other information. You can then better organize your `Order` class using these `Candy` classes by adding and subtracting them from a [Collection](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/collections-in-java-2/) of some sort to better handle the summarizing of the total.

Comment: It does explain better but the first one was good too! I appreciate your feedback. I know it's tedious with new learners but without tutoring, due to school closures, my luck is running dry. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. Product exchange programs modeling store transactions can be a bit complicated without knowing how to [Generalize](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/generalization-and-specialization-in-java/) your code for product types and their specific information so it will be useful to spend some time getting familiar with that as well as the various type of [Data Structures](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/data-structures/) built into Java.